# Insert a row if it does not exists with the same values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to insert a new row to my MySQL table *kh_comments* but it should only be inserted if a row with the same values does not exist.

This is how I tried it and I know that it is completely wrong:

```
public function prepare($author, $arr) {
    $conn = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db_name);

    foreach ($arr as $value) {

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO kh_comments WHERE NOT EXISTS (author, abstract) VALUES (?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $author, $value['id']);
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

I also tried using `INSERT IGNORE INTO ...` but that also didn't work for me.

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:**

This is how my table looks like:
[image]
In my SQL code I am NOT defining the `ID`. Would that be needed? If so, how the SQL will look then?

Comment: why the keyword `NOT EXISTS` ?

Comment: @jitendrapurohit That was a desperate attempt for trying to say "if the values do not exist".

Comment: Simply no way you can do that insert in it's present form because you don't have an index as mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Use INSERT IGNORE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the
>   INSERT statement are ignored. For example, without IGNORE, a row that
>   duplicates an **existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY** value in the table
>   causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With
>   IGNORE, the row is discarded and no error occurs. Ignored errors may
>   generate warnings instead, although duplicate-key errors do not.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO kh_comments(author,abstract) VALUES (?, ?)");

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $author, $value['id']);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

Note that for this approach (or the REPLACE INTO approach or even the ON DUPLICATE KEY approach) to be successfull you need to have a unique index on the fields that you don't want duplicated. As mentioned in the extract from the documentation above

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code but that doesn't work for me. It is still inserting rows with the same values.

Comment: Then you don't have a unique index on author and abstract. Create this and `INSERT IGNORE` will work.

Comment: @GarethD thank you, this is a good information. The ID (which may be the unique index) is not included in my SQL query. I have updated my question. Please take a look.

Comment: Glad to have been of use

Answer (score 1):

You might use `REPLACE INTO`

As the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html) says:

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the
>   table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE
>   index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

Comment: REPLACE INTO also works. The difference between REPLACE INTO and INSERT IGNORE is that REPLACE actually causes a database write with the record being replaced which means extra effort. Ignore, well just ignores it.

Comment: @e4c51 : Yea but as Reza says "INSERT IGNORE INTO ..." doesn't work. So i suggest this.

Comment: I assure you if INSERT IGNORE doesn't work, REPLACE INTO will not work either. You need indexes which the OP doesn't seem to have.

Comment: Cool. I think that too. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Glad to know you are thinking the same +1

Answer (score 0):

```
$check  = mysql_num_row(mysql_query("select * from  kh_comments where author  =    $auther   and  abstract=$value['id']"));
```

Comment: if($check==0)
{
    //your insert query
}